# Writing bash scripts

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I need to write a bash script that does the following:

> If it is given fewer than two arguments, it prints an appropriate
>   error and exits. Append to the file indicated by the first argument
>   the following information:
>
> - The time and date
> - One line for each of the second-through-last arguments, containing the number of lines in the file and then the name of the file
> - The total number of files in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do what you are asking for. Let me know if you have any problems with it.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
    echo "$0: Too few arguments. At least two required"
    exit 1
fi

date >> $1

arg_array=( "$@" )
i=1

while [ ${arg_array[$i]} ]
do
    echo `wc -l ${arg_array[$i]}` >> $1
    i=$(($i + 1))
done

echo $(($# - 1)) >> $1
```